# Rank of a matrix product with some conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{q\times n }, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p} $ with $\text{rank}(A)=q~$ and $~\text{rank}(B)=p$.

Additionally there is the condition: $n\geq p \geq q$.

I know that $\text{rank}(AB)\leq \min\{\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B)\}=q$.

I want to know if equality ($\text{rank}(AB)=q$)  always holds with the additional condition  $n\geq p \geq q~$, or are there some constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the equality does not necessarily hold. Consider the case of $n = 3,p=2,q=1$. Take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0},\quad  B = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0\\0&1}.
$$
We have $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = 0 < q = 1$.

---

One possibly helpful additional condition: if $p = n$ (so that $B$ is square) and both $A$ and $B$ have full rank, then it will always hold that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(A) = q$.

Comment: Unfortunately, [Sylvester's rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) is not much help here. It tells us that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)-n.
$$
Thus, we can ensure that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \geq q$ (and hence $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = q$) whenever
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)-n \geq q \implies\\
\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \geq n + q.
$$

Comment: Because $\operatorname{rank}(B)$ is at most $p \leq n$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq q$, this condition only holds if $p = n$ and both $A,B$ have full rank.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following example:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0& 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}, AB=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you can see, $rank(A) = 3$ , $rank(B) = 2$ and $rank(AB) = 0$. So it not always hold and constrain may be thought as A and B rank is *compressed* in the same side, roughly said. It is,

$$
A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, A_2B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$